# `ng-apexcharts` breaks unit tests

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-apexcharts

I'm trying to use `apexcharts` and `ng-apexcharts` on my home component. It was easy to get it working, but it's breaking my unit tests. I tried to look it up, but couldn't find anything that worked for me. The error happens on cleanup.

`HomeComponent`:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'hu-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    NavbarComponent,
    BarChartComponent
  ],
})
export class HomeComponent {}
```

home html:

```html
<hu-navbar></hu-navbar>
<hu-bar-chart test-id="bar-chart"></hu-bar-chart>
```

`BarChartComponent`:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'hu-bar-chart',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, NgApexchartsModule],
  templateUrl: './bar-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bar-chart.component.scss'],
})
export class BarChartComponent {
  @Input() series: ApexAxisChartSeries | ApexNonAxisChartSeries;
  @Input() chart: ApexChart;

  constructor() {
    this.series = [...];
    this.chart = {...};
  }
}
```

bar chart html:

```html
<apx-chart test-id="bar-chart" [series]="series" [chart]="chart"></apx-chart>
```

`HomeComponent`'s spec file:

```js
describe('HomeComponent', () => {
  let component: HomeComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HomeComponent>;
  let authenticationMock: AuthenticationMockService; // use mock to decouple unit tests from Firebase
  let page: HTMLElement;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    authenticationMock = new AuthenticationMockService();

    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HomeComponent],
    })
      .overrideProvider(AuthenticationService, { useValue: authenticationMock })
      .compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomeComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    page = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });

  it('should show the navbar', () => {
    expect(navbar()).not.toBeNull();
  });

  it('should show the bar chart', () => {
    expect(barChart()).not.toBeNull();
  });

  function navbar() {
    return page.querySelector('hu-navbar');
  }

  function barChart() {
    return page.querySelector('[test-id="bar-chart"]');
  }
});
```

And finally, the error:

```bash
console.error
    Error during cleanup of component {
      component: HomeComponent { __ngContext__: 7 },
      stacktrace: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'node')
      ...
```

This error happens in *every* test.  So far, I have only tried to add the following cleanup:

```js
  afterEach(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      fixture.destroy();
    }, 100);
  });
```

But that didn't help. I'm thinking maybe a solution is to mock it, but couldn't find info on how to do it.

There is a [smiliar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76365739/testing-react-apexcharts-apexcharts-with-jest-and-react-testing-library-snapsho) that hasn't been answered, but it's about `react-apexcharts`, not `ng-apexcharts`.

Comment: I have exactly the same error, I hope there will be a solution.

Comment: Hey @Lotfiction I found the solution and posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to add the following code to your `.spec.ts`. This should go inside the `beforeEach` that is auto-generated with `ng generate`:

```js
beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [...],
    }).compileComponents();

    // Add the code below
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'ResizeObserver', {
      writable: true,
      value:
        window.ResizeObserver ||
        jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
          observe: jest.fn(),
          unobserve: jest.fn(),
          disconnect: jest.fn(),
        })),
    });

    Object.defineProperty(global.SVGElement.prototype, 'getScreenCTM', {
      writable: true,
      value: jest.fn(),
    });

    Object.defineProperty(global.SVGElement.prototype, 'createSVGMatrix', {
      writable: true,
      value: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
        x: 10,
        y: 10,
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function
        inverse: () => {},
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function
        multiply: () => {},
      }),
    });
    // Code to add ends here
   
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TheComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

Comment: Worked for me, I have no longer the error. Thank you very much Tuma for sharing the fix. I hope it will be fixed soon in next versions